# Difference between * and + in regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Both giving the same result so what is the difference between "*" and "+" symbol.
How would I know which one to use.

```
var str= "oofo fooloo"
var StarSymbol= str.match(/fo*/g);
var PlusSymbol= str.match(/fo+/g)
console.log(StarSymbol)  // ["fo", "foo"]
console.log(PlusSymbol) // ["fo", "foo"]
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmr9t1sh/)

Comment: See if this helps http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: Your question is not really JavaScript specific.

Comment: with 1.6k score you could have find it easily. don't know why posted

Comment: @raghavendra: And still you answer the question...

Comment: yes man as you do like we do

Comment: Usually, you don't want to encourage people to ask questions that are going to be closed any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the same question again. So let me explain.

```
var str= "oofo fooloo"
var StarSymbol= str.match(/fo*/g);
var PlusSymbol= str.match(/fo+/g)
console.log(StarSymbol)  // ["fo", "foo"]
console.log(PlusSymbol) // ["fo", "foo"]
```

Ya, both gives the same result here(*for this input*) but `fo*` would match `f` alone where `fo+` would not. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times where `+` repeat the previous token one or more times. So this expects the previous token to be repeated atleast one time.

**Example:**

```
> var str= "f"
undefined
> str.match(/fo*/g);
[ 'f' ]
> str.match(/fo+/g);
null
>
```

Comment: _"You are asking the same question again"_, so why did you answer? You should've just close-voted it as a duplicate instead. Heck, you have the [tag:regex] mjölnir.

Comment: Don't encourage people to just keep posting, by answering them.

Answer (score 0):

`o*` search's for `zero or more` o's

`o+` search's for `one or more` o's

go through tutorials

Answer (score 0):

`*` means between `0` and infinite amount of times, while `+` means at least one (cannot be zero amount of times)

To be more verbose, `*` would be like writing `{0,}`, while `+` would be like writing `{1,}`

Comment: not sure. i think op didi. voting up. as it helps to the question

Comment: I did not downvote this answer.